# Different Free Storage Amounts on External SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-disk, mac-mini

This has really confused me. I recently bought an 1024 GB External SSD for my Mac mini, and put about 200 GB of files on it. However, whenever I click the space bar to see how much storage is left, it says that there’s only 710 GB left. Whenever I click get info, it says that the amount of storage left is 824 GB (which should be the correct amount). Is there a reason for this? Which one is the correct storage amount, and can I fix this issue at all?

Comment: Are you using Time Machine?

Comment: Nope, not on this particular SSD. I have a dedicated external HDD for time machine backups.